# my animated progress bar is not working?

Tags: jquery-ui, progress-bar

i was trying to make my code in html and for some reasong when i try to run my code inside the html document, this is not working, but i was trying same code on [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/gPfBC/)
 and my code it is working [http://jsfiddle.net/gPfBC/](http://jsfiddle.net)

by any chance can somebody try this code and give it to me the complete html code?

```
    <head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var p=0;

    $("#myProgressBar").progressbar({value:0});
        var timer = setInterval(function(){
            //This animates the bar
            $("#myProgressBar .ui-progressbar-value").animate({width: p+"%"}, 500);
            //This does static sets of the value
            //$("#myProgressBar").progressbar("option","value",p);
            p = p +3;
            if(p>33.33){
                $("#myProgressBar .ui-progressbar-value").animate({width: "33.33%"}, 500);
                //$("#myProgressBar").progressbar("option","value",100);
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
    },500);
});
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
  </style>
</head>
<body style=" background:url(ebay-bar/images/1.jpg) top left no-repeat; width:1099px; height:1050px;">
<a href="2.html" style="width:185px; height:31px;position:absolute; left: 198px; top: 516px;"></a>
<div style="width:954px; position:absolute; top:606px; left: 67px; height: 45px;">  
<div id="myProgressBar" style="height:43px;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the script on jsFiddle with jQuery 1.3.2 and jQuery UI 1.7.2, but your html page has included jQuery 1.5.

Replace

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your script is probably using functions that are deprecated in jQuery 1.5 or there is some problem between jQuery 1.5 and jQuery UI 1.8. Try using the latest versions of both jQuery and jQuery UI.

Comment: thank you so much, you were completely right! i have no words to take you! i was going crazy here :P